# Programa R: calcular BAL

Tags: r

Necesito calcular lo siguiente:

Tengo un data frame y quiero crear una variable a partir de otra de la siguiente manera. La variable nueva consiste en sumar todos los valores de la variable 2 siempre y cuando sean mayores que la variable 1. No se me ocurre ninguna forma de hacerlo.

```
 Caso     Var 1   Var2    Var a calcular
   1      15       25           135
   2      20       30           105
   3      30       45            60
   4      50       60             0
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de resolverlo:

```
df=data.frame(Caso=c(1,2,3,4), Var1=c(15,20,30,50), Var2=c(25,30,45,60))

myFun<-function(x){
  return(sum(df$Var2*(df$Var2>x[2] & df$Caso != x[1])))
  cat(x)
}

apply(df, 1, myFun)
[1] 135 130  60   0
```

Aunque creo que el segundo cálculo de tu tabla debería ser 130 lugar de 105? Ya que si entendí bien la lógica, 25 es mayor que 20, y cada vez que se suman los elementos se excluye sólo el registro actual en la suma de los "Var2"

Saludos